# Python - Disassociate command prompt and Spyder

Tags: python, terminal, spyder

when I am trying to make python do something from the command prompt, eg.

```
django-admin.py startproject testsite
```

it opens django-admin.py in the editor of Spyder, instead of running it.

Is there a way to work python in command prompt without Spyder interfering?

Edit - OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hello, it's Windows 8.1

Comment: And how did you install Spyder?

Comment: Then please contact Python(x,y) developers [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pythonxy) because this seems to be an installation problem where Python files get associated to Spyder instead of to the Python interpreter. Spyder is able to open Python files from the command line but it shouldn't be the first option to do it, to avoid things as the problem you are having.